# Meaning of the word "calls" in the context below

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What are the meanings of the word ***calls*** and the phrase ***make calls*** in the following sentence?

> Even some of the most sacred sporting events are not immune to
>   venality, as many of the officials have received substantial bribes to
>   make biased calls.

(*I don't think it means telephone calls...*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A referee's decision is often referred to as a call.  Such as, he was called out at second base.  Or the ref called him for interference.  Or in your case, someone might complain, "The ref made a terrible call!"

This can happen outside of sports, also. "Where should we eat?"  "I don't know, you make the call." (Decision)

Answer (score 1):

You are right; it doesn't mean telephone calls in the sentence.

When a referee or umpire makes biased calls in a sport, it means that he makes  unfair or prejudiced signals or decisions favoring one player or side over the other.